# MVVM good practice?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a treeView(FunctionTreeView) and want to exchange data between the View and the ViewModel.

This is my View

```
private void FunctionTreeView_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem parent;
        int pIndex,cIndex = 0;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            EnteredKeys.Length = 0;
        else
            EnteredKeys.Append(e.Key.ToString());

        if (FunctionTreeView.Items.IndexOf(FunctionTreeView.SelectedItem) != -1)
        {
            //if selected is parent, get parent item. 
            parent = FunctionTreeView.Tag as TreeViewItem;
            cIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeViewItem child = FunctionTreeView.Tag as TreeViewItem;
            parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(child) as TreeViewItem;
            cIndex = parent.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(child);
        }

        pIndex = FunctionTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(parent);
        ViewModel.PerformSearch(pIndex,cIndex);
```

The PerformSearch function resides in the ViewModel. Is it good practise / the best way, to access the UI elements like this in the View? I'm new to MVVM.

Comment: No, it isn't. Take a look at [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Comment: But I can't pass values via commands right?

Comment: Well you can. You need to use [CommandParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that, it will be passed as a parameter to `ICommand.Execute`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    //Your Code
}
```

Read the following links. It will help you.

[Basic MVVM and ICommand usuage example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-usuage-example)

[Commands in MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM)